# Running android emulator as server

Tags: android, tcp, android-emulator, tcpserver

I want to receive the AT command from android emulator and send the reply back from TCP client program which is written in C.

I am running Android ICS emulator on ubuntu-10.4 system as server by giving command "`emulator -shell-serial tcp::4444,server`" and in another terminal I am running TCP client written in C trying to connect to the same port.

I am able to see the emulator GUI coming up but I am not receiving any AT command in client.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, in the emulator command i need to pass -radio instead -shell-serial. now I am able to receive all the AT commands in my client program